# SQL Server stored proc performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have an ASP.NET app that has the following SQL query in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT @result = COUNT(id)
FROM course_tracking
WHERE employee_number = @employee_number
AND course_code = @course_code

IF @result = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO COURSE TRACKING
END
ELSE
    UPDATE COURSE TRACKING
```

The `Course Tracking` table has almost a million rows in it and SQL Profiler shows between 40k and 50k reads each time this proc is executed which is once ever couple of seconds.

Since I'm not a SQL Server perf guy...what is the best way to correct this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure `course_code` and `employee_number` are both indexed.  A covering index should work fine.

Comment: What SQL Server version? Because SQLServer 2008 gives you the `MERGE` ability which is great for upserts like this.

Comment: @JNK, won't he have to include the id column for the count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex,

There can be a number of reasons for the large amount of reads, and I believe that @Jonathan's answer will help, or mask the problem for now. The reason for getting lots of reads will be because you are missing some critical indexes, and/or your table statistics is not up to date, or it is turned off.

Now doing perf tuning on a large table like this can be complicated, if it is used by many other procedures, views and queries. Because changing any indexes can have a massive impact on other queries that are running fine now, but then again if your table is lacking any indexes, any change might just help. Things to consider when you attempt optimising something like this is:

1. How frequently is this query ran
2. When it run's does it impact other processes on the system
3. What is the most frequent operation
   on this table, inserts or updates?

If this query is ran once a day, or very infrequently, and it is not impacting other processes, I might be inclined to leave it. But if this is a process that runs very frequently and/or it is impacting other processes, then you need to fix it. Now by fixing it, it can be as simple as just adding a `WITH(NOLOCK)` table hint if you find it is blocking, but if it is ran very frequently, then look at indexes and statistics.

If you have a lot of inserts on this table, then any extra index will impact insert performance, but it will speed up updates. Then comes index fill factor etc etc. My point is that perf tuning on a Sql box is very complicated, and requires the entire picture most of the time.

SO what I would suggest is that you take a few hints here and, because nobody knows your system as well as you, you can make some decisions, and experiment, and learn from it too! Enable your Query Execution Plan and look at it, see if you see any table scans, they are bad, and indicate a lack of proper indexes, so does key lookups.

But looking at your query you have given here and ignoring any other factors, here is what I would suggest.

Make sure you have a NON CLUSTERED index that have `employee_number` and `course_code` in the index. If it is Sql 2008 you can add some included columns too if you have other queries filtering on these two columns, but output other columns. As far as if they should be ascending or descending in the index is up to you, but leave them both as ascending.

Then for the query, use what @Jonathan (+1 for you!) proposed, with a minor change, add a WITH(NOLOCK) hint on the table. This will tell the Sql optimiser not to lock the table when it reads it, but you will be able to read dirty data. Normally not a problem, unless it is a highly transactional table, lots of updates and inserts going on the whole time.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM course_tracking WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE employee_number = @employee_number
      AND course_code = @course_code)
BEGIN
     UPDATE COURSE TRACKING
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO COURSE TRACKING
END
```

Also, check if your statistics are updated automatically on the database, if not, create a maintenance job that will update it once a day, when the server is least active. Create a SQL Agent job with this as the query `EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN'`

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM course_tracking
WHERE employee_number = @employee_number
AND course_code = @course_code)
BEGIN
     UPDATE COURSE TRACKING
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO COURSE TRACKING
END
```

Answer (score 1):

If your query is actually updating the rows `WHERE employee_number = @employee_number AND course_code = @course_code)`, then you could try this technique:

```
UPDATE course_tracking
SET ...
WHERE employee_number = @employee_number
  AND course_code = @course_code;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  INSERT INTO course_tracking
  ...
```

Comment: This is inferior to the `EXISTS` answer above

Comment: @Matthew PK: There are two of them, albeit almost the same. Anyway, I don't think so. With the EXISTS approach the table is searched twice in case the condition is met. With the solution I'm offering it happens only once. What am I missing?

Comment: I could be wrong and I apologize if so... I would expect `EXISTS` to be more performant because it can stop searching after locating one match whereas your approach will continue a complete scan (unless there is some rule for uniqueness in place)

Comment: @Matthew PK: To some degree the uniqueness is implied in the OP's example query. But that doesn't matter. If there are records that meet the condition, you first have to find at least one with EXISTS, then search all the table on the same condition to make updates. If there are no matching records, then you first search the table in vain, then insert. With my solution, you simply omit the initial check-only search, the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL 2008, the `MERGE` syntax is good. Pinal Dave has a good walkthrough http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

```
MERGE course_tracking AS c
ON c.employee_number =  @employee_number
AND c.course_code  = @course_code 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE STUFF
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT STUFF
GO
```

Comment: The syntax is all good, but without proper indexes and bad table design, this will only mask the problem, if it will mask it at all.

Comment: @Ryk without good design and indices no upsert syntax will matter. This is, at least, a concise method on a proper DB.

Comment: I agree that it is concise, but perf wise it arguably the same as an IF..ELSE condition, and in my opinion much more readable. But this comes down to personal taste and readability.